# Events changing state in CQRS

Tags: events, cqrs, saga

This should be easy to follow, but after some reading I still can find an answer.

So, say that the user needs to change his mobile number, to accomplished that, we might have a  command as: ChangedUserMobileNumber

holding the new number. The domain responsible for handling the command will perform the change in the aggregate and publish an event: UserMobilePhoneChanged

There is a subscriber for that event in another domain, which also holds the user mobile number in its aggregate but according to our software architect, events can not old any data so what we end up is rather stupid to say the least:

The Domain 1, receives the command to update the mobile number, the number is updated and one event is published, also, because the event cannot hold data, the command handler in the Domain 1 issues yet another command which is sent to Domain 2. The subscriber of that event lives in Domain 2 too, we then have a Saga to handle both the event and the command.

In terms of implementation we are using NServiceBus, so we have this saga to handle these message and in it we have this line of code, where the entity.IsMobilePhoneUpdated field stored in a saga entity is changed when the event is handeled.

bool isReady = (entity.IsMobilePhoneUpdated && entity.MobilePhoneNumber != null);

Effectively the Saga is started by both the command and the event raised in the Domain 1, and until this condition is met, the saga is kept alive.

If it was up to me, I would be sending the mobile number in the event itself, I just want to get a few other opinions on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how a UserMobilePhoneChanged event could be useful in any way unless it contained the new phone number. User asks to change a number, the event shoots out that it has. Should be very simple indeed. Why does your architect say that events shouldn't contain any information?

Comment: I really don't know.

I was told that the architect have this conviction that events should have no data, and since I was a software architect before joining this company I don't what to ask the architect why he has this conviction, because I might get in troubles.
I joined this company a couple of months ago so I don't really want to create a problem on this, but the more a look at their implementation of a SOA using NServiceBus the more I realize that they got most of the basics wrong.
I just wanted an input on this, I've worked with SOA CQRS before,but I thought I was missing someyhing new.

Comment: All the system is built around this concept. Whenever there is a change performed by a command, an event is created, which doesn't carry the state and a new domain command is also issued with the changed data. Crazy stuff, and the more I look the more I realize that this guys got into SOA with CQRS without knowing what is it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first event based system i've designed events also had no data. I also did enforce that rule. At the time that sounded like a clever decision. After a while i realised that it was dumb, and i was making a lot of workarounds because of it. Also this caused a lot of querying form the event subscribers, even for trivial data. I had no problem changing this "rule" after i realised i'm doing it wrong.

Events should have all the data required to make them meaningful. Also they should only have the data that makes sense for that event. ( No point in having the user address in a ChangePhoneNumber message )

If your *architect* imposes such a restriction, it's not going to be easy to develop a CQRS system. How are the read models updated? Since the events have no data then you either query something to get the data ( the write side ? ) of find some way of sending a command to the read model ( then what's the point of publishing events? ). To fix your problem you should try to have a **professional** discussion with this architect, preferably including other tech heads and without offending anybody try to get him to relax this constraint.

On argument you could use is Event Sourcing. Event Sourcing is complementary to CQRS and would not make sense without events that have data. Even more when using event sourcing, the only data you have is the data stored in the events. Even if you don't actually implement event sourcing you can use it's existence as a reason for events to have data.

There is little point in finding a technical solution to a people problem.

Comment: Hi Iulian,

But you must have read from somewhere that this was the proper way of doing it,no? I am sure that our architect is smart enough,but maybe he just read some kind of document advocating that this was the real way of practicing CQRS.

Comment: Read models! We don't have them either, we have the queries and the commands, but the same model to read/write, and we are not using any aggregate roots either, it is all a mess,but in fairness some of these problems where already here when the architect joined the company,so I was told.

Comment: You're completely right, and sometimes I find it so strange that people follow all this concepts so blindly without stopping to think about it for a while, one can easy get it, that this is all wrong, but then again it it not my call and in the end I was already call to attention because I was doing too many questions. The worst thing is that, even knowing that things are wrong you must continue doing it wrong.

Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: If the fact that you are asking to many questions is not appreciated i strongly suggest you consider looking for another job :). That is one of the most important qualities i look for in the devs i work with.

Comment: I've mentored new guys  in the past as well, and that is a quality I also very much appreciated, we know that when people just yes all the time, without questioning, something is not right. As for looking for another job, I really like this company, but its is really difficult to cope with same stuff, like doing things wrongly when you know they are wrong. I had to relocated to get this job, and I also had to come down for being a software architect to a senior dev, I just though the move was going to be easier.